# Linked List : remove() and search() methods do not work properly when value not in list

Tags: c++, linked-list

So I'm attempting to create a Template Link List class in C++. Everything works perfectly, including the remove() and search() in question , EXCEPT when I call the two methods on a value not in the LinkList. Ideally, I'd like the methods to return after it's discovered that the value is not in the list  , however, I feel like the methods continue on and attempt to remove or search for a value further because when I run the executable, I get the "Segementation Fault (core dumped)" error. The program prints the correct error if the methods are called on an empty list.

The list is singly linked with a head and is implemented using "smart nodes" (i.e. nodes that contain their own methods to compliment the matching class methods as opposed to "dumb nodes" that contain no methods and require the class methods to create temporary pointers to the nodes and iterate through the list).

Here are the implementations for search() and remove(). Of course, I can provide more of the code if necessary:

```
//==========================REMOVE================================

template <class T>
void TLinkedList<T> :: remove(T value){
  if(!head){                               //if there is no head
    std::cerr << "Error: List is Empty" << std::endl;  // The list is empty
    return;
  }
  if(head->data == value){
    listSize--;     //decremenets listSize since a node is removed
    node * temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete head;
    return;
  }
  else{
    if(head->remove(value)){  //If something was removed as a result of the node's remove()
      listSize--;
      return;                 //decrement listSize since something was removed
    }
    else{                     //else if nothing removed
      std::cerr << "Error : Value not in list" << std::endl;
      return;
    }
  }
}

template <class T>
bool TLinkedList<T> :: node :: remove(T value ){  //returns a bool. If something was removed, returns true. If nothing was removed, returns false
  if(next-> data == value){
    node * temp = next;
    next = next->next;
    delete temp;
    return true; //something removed
  }
  if(!next){
    return false;
  }
  else{
    return next -> remove(value);
  }
}


//==============SEARCH===================
template <class T>
T TLinkedList<T> :: search(T value){
   if(!head){
    std::cerr << "Error: List is empty" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
  if(head->data == value){  //If head's data is the value searched for
    return head->data;      //return head's data
  }
  else{
    return head->search(value);
  }

}

template <class T>
T TLinkedList<T> :: node :: search(T value){
  if(data == value){
    return data;
  }
  if(!next){
    std::cerr << "Error: Value not in list" << std::endl;
    return 0;
  }
  else{
    return next->search(value);
  }
}
```

So, for a main() such as:

```
int main(){

    TLinkedList ll;
    ll.prepend(5); //adds 5 to list
    ll.remove(4); // value of 4 not in list
    // OR ll.search(4);
    return 0;
}
```

The cerr does not happen and the 'Segmentation Fault (core dumped)' error is given.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Also, in the search() method you may notice that I return 0; when an error occurs. This implementation was an attempt to stop the method when the error is encountered; ideally I'd rather the search not return anything if an error is encountered

Comment: You should have your search function return the node that contains the element being searched for or return `nullptr` if the element is not found. Then your remove will simply call search and then delete the element

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin with that your methods remove contain several bugs. Consider at first method `void TLinkedList<T> :: remove(T value);`
In this code snippet you delete the head of the list

```
  if(head->data == value){
    listSize--;     //decremenets listSize since a node is removed
    node * temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete head;
    return;
  }
```

Must be

```
  if(head->data == value){
    listSize--;     //decremenets listSize since a node is removed
    node * temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete temp; // <==
    return;
  }
```

In function `bool TLinkedList<T> :: node :: remove(T value );`you do not check whether data member next is equal to 0. So this code has undefined behavior

```
  if(next-> data == value){ <== next can be equal to 0
```

You should change the order of these conditions

```
  if(!next){
    return false;
  }
  if(next-> data == value){
    node * temp = next;
    next = next->next;
    delete temp;
    return true; //something removed
  }
```

As fro methods search I would define them the following way

```
template <class T>
TLinkedList<T>::node * TLinkedList<T>::search( const T &value ) const
{
    return ( head == nullptr ? nullptr : head->search( value ) );
}

template <class T>
TLinkedList<T> :: node * TLinkedList<T>::node::search( const T &value ) const
{
   if ( data == value ) return this;

   return  ( next == nullptr ? nullptr : next->search( value ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment above, this is what your search functions should look like:

```
//==============SEARCH===================
template <class T>
T TLinkedList<T>::search(T value){
    if(!head){
        std::cerr << "Error: List is empty" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else if(head->data == value){  //If head's data is the value searched for
        return head->data;      //return head's data
    }

    typename TLinkedList<T>::node *temp = head->search(value);
    if (temp)
        return temp->data;
    return 0;
}
```

**node::search**

```
template <class T>
typename TLinkedList<T>::node *TLinkedList<T> :: node:: search(T value) {
    if(data == value){
        return this;
    }
    else if(!next){
        std::cerr << "Error: Value not in list" << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }
    return next->search(value);
}
```

**TLinkedList::remove(T)**

```
//==========================REMOVE================================

template <class T>
void TLinkedList<T> :: remove(T value){
    if(!head) {                               //if there is no head
        std::cerr << "Error: List is Empty" << std::endl;  // The list is empty
        return;
    }
    else if(head->data == value){
        listSize--;     //decremenets listSize since a node is removed
        node *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete tmp;
        return;
    }

    node *tmp = head->search(value);

    if (tmp != nullptr) {
        listSize--;     //decremenets listSize since a node is removed
        node *tmp2 = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
        delete tmp2;
    }
    else std::cerr << "Error : Value not in list" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is broken in several places. Here are those I spotted:

1. If the first node is to be removed, the new head is deleted instead of the first node. You probably meant to use

   ```
   delete temp;
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   delete head;
   ```
2. If there is only one node in the list which doesn't match the value, the `...::node::remove()` function will access a non-existing node. You need to check if `next` points to something beofre accessing its value. Actually, since eventually the list will have a tail of just one element, this explains one of your crashes. You probably wanted something like

   ```
   if (!next) { /* error goes here */ }
   else if (next->value == value) { /* successful return goes here */ }
   else { /* recursion goes here */ }
   ```
3. The `...::node::search()` function has the same problem, explaining your other crash. This function seems to have a fairly pointless interface, though: you search for a value and if a value is found the searched value is returned. Otherwise `0` is returned which means all types `T` you can use with the `search()` methods need to have a constructor which accepts `0`. This seems to be a fairly harsh restriction. You probably want to return an iterator to the found object or an iterator to the end of the list.

Note that a recursive approach to managing lists is bound to not work too well in C++. The way the functions are written they allow tail recursion but I don't think that C++ has any guarnatee that tail recusion is actually implemented, i.e., you can easily run out of stack space when traversing long lists.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the error might comes from your `preprend()` method. Furthermore, as others said in their post, your implementation lacks of checks and safety.

Why don't you use `STL` or `Boost` linked list which already exist and meet purpose in general?